variable service not initialized in the default constructor despite the RequiredArgsConstructor annotation
When I try to launch my spring-boot app, this error is thrown

java: variable service not initialized in the default constructor

Here is the controller I get the error from:
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/internal")
public class OrchestrationController {
    private final OrchestratorService service;

    @PostMapping("/generate")
    public ResponseEntity<UUID> generate(@RequestBody SomeDTO dto) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.publishMessage(dto));
    }
}

I have created the application with spring initializr with the lombok dependency, so I have these two parts in my pom.xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
.
.
.
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

n.b. Enable annotation processing is checked and lombok plugin is installed.
Does anyone have any clue that could help me?
Thank you very much.
I tried disabling the cache and restarting, but it didn't work.
I tried maven clean install & generate folders and sources & maven reload didn't work neither.
I tried to removing and install with the annotationProcessorPaths off and on, no result.
I tried to removing the target folder, and then doing maven clean install --> no result.
I tried launching the app via the CLI, and it works! But I would like to do it via intellij too.
EDIT:
Here is my OrchestratorService class as @VedantK suggested:
@Service
public interface OrchestratorService {
    UUID publishMessage(SomeDTO demand);

    void onReceiveMessage(SomeVM response);
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class OrchestratorServiceImpl implements OrchestratorService {

    @Override
    public UUID publishMessage(SomeDTO demand) {
        SomeVM vm = new SomeVM ();
        return vm.getId();
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceiveMessage(SomeVM response) {
        handle(response);
    }

    private void handle(PlaylistEndJobPayloadVM response) {
        log.debug("Sending REST request ...");
    }
}


You write that it works from the CLI but not from IntelliJ: did you enable annotation processing in IntelliJ too? You find the setting in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors
